# Getting list of shapes on border of map using ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, shapefile

I have the following map of a state with its precincts inside of it:

[image]

Is there any way that I can get a list of the precincts that are on the border of the state? I have been looking through the different tools that ArcMap has but I cant find anything useful.

Answer (score 4):

1. [Dissolve](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/dissolve.htm) to get one big state polygon
2. Use [Select by Location](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/using-select-by-location.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_C99C9DD7EB234B85B756CDE2C2A1CD76) with spatial query "Share a line segment with" to select precincts that are on the border of dissolved state polygon

You will see the selected polygons listed in the attribute table

[image]

Comment: I think the spatial query "share a line segment with" may also work (without the switch selection).

Comment: Yes, that is better